# Oracle Managed Data Provider downloaded via NuGet is missing DLL

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, nuget

I want to switch to using the Oracle Managed Data Provider for my ASP.NET site. I run the following command at the package manager console:

```
Install-Package odp.net.managed
```

It says it installed successfully. But when I look in my `/bin` folder I just see `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll.refresh`. There is no `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` file. I tried removing the NuGet package and reinstalling it several times, but it never actually pulled in the DLL.

How do I get the DLL? I'd like to stick to using NuGet. Downloading from Oracle's site and unzipping their files etc is a pain.

Note, this is an ASP.NET Web Site, not an ASP.NET Web Application (it's a legacy site that we're unwilling to change at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into the directory that contained the solution in Windows Explorer. Then I navigated to...

```
packages\odp.net.managed.121.1.2\lib\net40
```

And the DLL was there. I manually copied that into my site's BIN folder. Not sure why I had to manually do this, as I've installed many NuGet packages before on ASP.NET web sites.